# How to prevent scrollIntoView(true) from happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing a 3rd party JS based webapp into my website, and they use scrollIntoView in their JS to scroll down to their app when the page loads, this has some negative consequences for my page, as it scrolls right past everything above their app every time someone visits the page.

I've asked them to allow me to opt out of this behavior, and they replied that many of their customers have requested the same, and they are discussing what to do.

However, in the meantime, I would like to just add my own script into the body or header of the page to ignore this behavior.

I've tried setting the scroll position onload on the containing div, but the offending script doesn't happen until after the page is loaded, so it would need to wait until it tries to execute scrollintoview, and then prevent it from happening.

Any suggestions? I'm not a coder, but I can copy and paste like a champ. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable `scrollIntoView` functionality altogether, you could do this:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = function() {};
```

Comment: Noob question here, do I verbatim `<script>HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = function() {};</script>` in the header or body, or do I need to declare the HTMLElement like `<script>body.prototype.scrollIntoView = function() {};</script>` or div or ?

Comment: Your first one can go in either the head or the body (assuming HTML5).  The word "HTMLElement" causes it to apply to all elements.  (I don't think the method does anything on the body, because the body is always in view.)

Comment: I just added the verbatim script to my header and it worked beautifully, you are my personal hero rick, thanks for being awesome!